Jest Test with Vue3 - $q.loading is undefined
Currently migrating a project from Vue2 to Vue3, and it's mostly done - the app seems to work fine. However, Jest tests seem to have trouble passing. I have updated Vue Test Utils to V2 for Vue3 compatibility.
This is the error:
...\Request.vue:67412
              _this4.$q.loading.hide();
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hide')
    at hide (...\Request.vue:530:33)
    at tryCatch (...\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
    at Generator.next (...\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (...\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:17)
    at _next (...\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:17:9)

Unfortunately, the line numbers do not line up with what is described (i.e., Request.vue is really only ~10k lines, and line 530 does not actually have hide called).
After a bit of investigation, this is the line:
this.$q.loading.hide();

Called directly in Request.vue (i.e., not called from an imported function or anything). Again, confusingly, this is not an issue when actually running the application, and the loading screen hides just fine. Disabling this line causes the loading screen to stay forever, expectedly.
I have included this line at the top of the jest test file:
import { installQuasarPlugin } from '@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest';

installQuasarPlugin();

As per instructions for testing quasar related items in Vue3.
Following is the package.json for relevant items:
"dependencies": {
...
    "quasar": "^2.16.4",
...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@quasar/app-webpack": "^3.13.2",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing": "^2.0.6",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-e2e-cypress": "^5.2.0",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest": "^3.0.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.4.27",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.6",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^29.2.6",
    "audit-ci": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "cypress": "^13.2.0",
    "cypress-ntlm-auth": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
},

Note that I also tried doing $q.loading.show() in front of $q.load.hide() just in case it was some weird quirk, but I suppose unsurprisingly, it causes the same error.
I'm hesitant to do:
$q.loading?.hide()

Just to get the test to pass, as I feel like this'll have unexpected side effects in the actual application.

try installQuasarPlugin({ plugins: { Loading } });.  also will need import { Loading } from 'quasar';

Thanks! I can't confirm this works yet as it appears to brought a different bug with shallowMount, will investigate for a bit and get back to you

so unfortuantely, looks like the same error persists even with this
